# What is the difference between extends Object with Observable and extends Observable

Tags: dart

What is the difference between extends Object with Observable and extends Observable as applied to the class below.

The result is the same when the application is run.

```dart
library models;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Person extends Object with Observable {
  @observable String name;
  @observable bool signedAgreement = false;

  Person();

  Person.from(Person other) {
    name = other.name;
    signedAgreement = other.signedAgreement;
  }

  blank() {
    name = '';
    signedAgreement = false;
  }
}


library models;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Person extends Observable {
  @observable String name;
  @observable bool signedAgreement = false;

  Person();

  Person.from(Person other) {
    name = other.name;
    signedAgreement = other.signedAgreement;
  }

  blank() {
    name = '';
    signedAgreement = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There no difference in the behaviour between this two declarations.

Here's [a quote from Florian Loitsch](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/seJMycuZ2MU/s4TO2U6xpp4J) :

> When you extend "Object" with a mixin the first mixin can always take the place of "Object".

The only little difference is in class hierarchy (`superclass` are not the same) :

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

abstract class Mixin {}
class A extends Mixin {}
class B extends Object with Mixin {}

main() {
  print(reflectClass(A).superclass); 
  // => ClassMirror on 'Mixin'

  print(reflectClass(A).superclass.superclass);
  // => ClassMirror on 'Object'

  print(reflectClass(B).superclass); 
  // => ClassMirror on 'dart.core.Object with .Mixin'

  print(reflectClass(B).superclass.superclass); 
  // => ClassMirror on 'Object'
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer.