# Using with to bind logic class

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new dart/flutter programmer. I'm trying to understand the difference between implements, extends and with.

For example is it ok to bind a logic class to a state by using "with"?

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with HomeLogic //homelogic is a class for DB connection and logic things{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(connectedUser) //in HomeLogic I have connectedUser string,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764838/what-is-the-difference-between-extends-object-with-observable-and-extends-observ)

Comment: That anwer is not enough for me.